# MonoBehaviour objects becoming null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project, I have a MonoBehaviour class, PlayerController, that contains an array of objects of another MonoBehaviour class, WaypointController. This array is populated by dragging objects into the Inspector. The problem is that the objects in the array start out fine when testing the game, but become null, and I cannot figure out why or exactly where. I am not destroying the objects (knowingly) or loading other scenes. How can I fix this?

The WaypointController objects encapsulate a CanvasGroup, and I'm toggling the CanvasGroup's alpha and interactable fields during the game.

This is the class that contains the array:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    // This is the array that is populated from the Inspector
    // by dragging and dropping objects. 
    public WaypointController[] waypoints;
    int currentWaypoint = 0;

    // Called whenever a button in a WaypointController's canvas is clicked.
    public void ContinueTour() {
        Debug.Log ("Continuing tour");
        Debug.Log("ContinueTour: currentWaypoint=" + currentWaypoint);
        if (waypoints [currentWaypoint] != null) {
            Debug.Log ("Hiding waypoint " + currentWaypoint);
            waypoints [currentWaypoint].HideDescription ();

        } else {
            // This message is not displayed for the first WaypointController,
            // but it starts being displayed by the time second 
            // WaypointController is current.
            Debug.Log ("ERROR: Current waypoint is null");
        }
    }
}
```

The objects that are becoming null are of this class:

```
public class WaypointController : MonoBehaviour {

    Canvas waypointDescriptionCanvas;
    CanvasGroup canvasGroup;


    void Awake() {
        waypointDescriptionCanvas = GetComponentInChildren<Canvas> ();

        if (waypointDescriptionCanvas == null) {
            Debug.Log ("Could not get canvas.");
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Disabling description");
            // The description is not visible initially.
            canvasGroup = waypointDescriptionCanvas.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
            HideDescription();

        }
    }

    // Make the description canvas visible.
    public void ShowDescription() {
        Debug.Log ("ShowDescription");
        Vector3 direction = waypointDescriptionCanvas.transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position;
        waypointDescriptionCanvas.transform.forward = direction;
        canvasGroup.alpha = 1;
        canvasGroup.interactable = true;
    }

    public void HideDescription() {
        Debug.Log ("HideDescription");
        if (canvasGroup != null) {
            canvasGroup.alpha = 0;
            canvasGroup.interactable = false;

        } else {
            Debug.Log ("canvasGroup is null");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors during runtime before this problem occurs at all?

Comment: No, not that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Player object, to which PlayerController is attached, was instantiated from a prefab. In one object, its button's onClick was pointing to the prefab and not to the instance. The prefab did not have valid objects in the waypoints array.

I resolved the issue by making sure the GameObject player was selected as the source of the PlayerController.ContinueTour function when setting the button's onClick.